# Help with Vehicle Position from Velocity Equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, physics, kinematics

I performance test cars with a draggy, it measures the change in position over time... sound familiar? anyway.. see below. I was able to enter my acceleration data in numbers and plot the equation relatively precisely with the below equation.

What I can't seem to figure out is how I can obtain the position of my car (in feet) from the equation; namely, find out at $1320$ ft.. how long it took my car to get there &/or vice versa (enter a time and obtain a distance). I know that I started at $0$ mph & at $130$ mph my car had traveled $2067.32$ feet. I also know at $60$ mph I had traveled $202.73$ feet.

[image: plot]

I have tried integrating my velocity equation from $1320$ to $0$... however this rendered no results. Any ideas out there?

Answer (score 1):

$$v=\frac{dx}{dt}$$so$$\int_0^Tv(t)dt=\int_{x(0)}^{x(T)}dx$$
In your case you calculate the integral by summing

Comment: This is the integral: 1.4297 x + 10.3245 x^2 - 0.6247 x^3 + 0.0264 x^4 - 0.00048 x^5 + C       I do not know what the constant would be in this situation. Also.. summing what? (T) should be TIME in seconds. But If I enter my final time of 16.56 seconds.. it should equal my final distance of 2067.32. It does not. It outputs 1405.65.. which is not the correct distance covered (or even close).

Comment: Obviously you have an issue with units conversion. Change the speed from mph to ft/s.

Comment: Dead on man. Thank you. That unit issue was throwing me off big time! Thank you for your help. Next time I put it on paper instead of numbers. I was not paying attention enough to units; clearly those are important lol

Comment: It would be so much easier if everything would be in m, m/s, ... :)